# Can someone help me with proving roots?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, roots

$F(x) = 2x^3 +x^2−4x−2+cosx$. How do I prove that F(x) has exactly three solutions(roots) and is strictly increasing on $(-\infty,a_1)$ and $(a_2,\infty)$, and strictly decreasing on $(a_1,a_2)$ ? Where $a_1$ and $a_2$ are local maximum or minimum points.

So this is what I have been thinking.

1. I could use IVT I find out that I have $F(x)=0$ in three intervals if i plug in some values for $x$. But still, it would not prove that $F(x)$ have exactly three solutions.
2. If I set $F '(x)=0$ I could prove that there is exactly three solutions and where $F(x)$ is increasing/decreasing, but this equation is not possible to solve.

What should I do?

Comment: What are a1 and a2? The question makes no sense without that information.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Ohh, I'm sorry, I have forgotten to add some extra information. I will do it now.

Answer (score 1):

One long method is that you can start from the third derivative and go back, since $F'''(x)=12 +\sin x$ and you can easily sketch that, now sketch and interpret the variations of $F''$ then $F'$ and finally $F$.

EDIT:

You're right $F'(x)$ has 2 roots that are about $-0.9$ and $0.7$ and between the 2 roots $F'$ is under the $x$-axis, so $F$ is increasing then decreasing (between $-0.9$ and $0.7$) and then increasing, which means that it have a local maximum and a local minimum, and since the maximum is positive and the minimum is negative this means that it have only $3$ distinct roots.

Comment: I have no problems with using the third derivative and then proving that f''(x) has only one solution, but then I have to prove that there is only two solutions for f'(x) and the I get stuck again

Comment: But how can I do prove this without calculating the solutions? My teacher says it is not necessary to find the solutions, but only prove that they exist.

Comment: So F'''(x)=12+sinx>0 so F''(x) will only have one solution due to the IVT. Then I need to prove that F'(x) has exactly two solutions a1 and a2 and prove that F'(x) is decreasing on (-inf,a) and increasing on (a, inf). But how do I do thatt? I'm not supposed to calculate the exact values of a, a1 and a3, if you see?

Comment: I was supposed to write a2 and not a3

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Consider that $F(x)$ is bounded by
$$G(x)= 2x^3 +x^2−4x−1$$ and
$$H(x)= 2x^3 +x^2−4x−3$$

Comment: Can I then set G(x)= 0 and H(x)=0 and find out that I can have 3 solutions, and then take the derivative of both?

Comment: @Mathomat55. First, show that $G(x)=0$ and $H(x)=0$ have three real roots.

Comment: Okay, I will try this!

Comment: Leibovici. When calculate H(x)=0 I only get two roots: x=3/2 and x=1.5

Answer (score 1):

use te equation $$\cos(x)=-2x^3-x^2+4x+2$$ and use that $$|\cos(x)|\le 1$$
Ok, you have also $$|-2x^3-x^2+4x+2|\le 1$$

Comment: Ohh, okay. So if solve for x, I then prove that there is exactly three solutions?